# Floating Action Button: Is there a straightforward way to make a button smaller than default mini?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is a screenshot of Button default sizes (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/floating-action-button)

[image]

The size of `mini` button is 40x40px. Is there an easy way to reduce size to 30x30 or any other custom size? Say, by providing a `prop={{size: '30:30'}}` or somehow by styling.

Answer (score 4):

For those still looking for a solution, I had to apply the style via the 'iconStyle' prop.

```
const myStyle = {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
};

<FloatingActionButton iconStyle={ myStyle } />
```

For me, however, this caused an issue with my icon being off center. So myStyle then became:

```
const myStyle = {
    height: 20,
    lineHeight: '20px',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    width: 20,
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can resize a Fab by using transform: scale() since it is a svg

```
<Fab style={{ transform: 'scale(0.7)' }} aria-label="edit">
    <EditIcon />
</Fab>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have only found this hacky (but at least working) solution:

```
.button-class {
  > button {
    height: 22px !important;
    width: 22px !important;
    svg {
      height: 22px !important;
      width: 16px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to change the size of a FAB button is using the size prop.

```
size = {'small' | 'medium' | 'large'}
```

Like this:

```
<Fab size="small">
    <AddIcon />
</Fab>
```

Is the new syntax being used after **Material Design UI v1** was released on *May 18, 2018*.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me when I had this problem.

If you set the inline style for the FAB with min/max dimensions specified, it should work:

```
const myStyle = {
    maxHeight: "30px",
    minHeight: "30px",
    minWidth: "30px",
    maxWidth: "30px",
};

return 
    <Fab style={myStyle}><Fab/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a style to the FAB with height and width set to 20?

I've used something like this before and it's been fairly straightforward to work with

```
const styles = {

    fabStyle: {
        height: '20',
        width: '20',
    }
}

<FloatingActionButton ... style={styles.fabStyle}/>
```

This should apply the fabStyle style to your FAB, provided you don't have any parent components that have different styling already applied.

I don't really use the `prop={{size: '30:30'}}` syntax for styling of components, and I'm not sure it works with react/mui. It's pretty easy to use the style prop on components and then assign them a style you define. Check out the page where you found the fab screenshot above and you will see they use a similar idea on styling.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't make it.

Comment: Do you have your fab wrapped in a div by chance? Another thing to try is setting the background color so that you can differentiate where the fab's actual graphical representation stops, just in case it's blending with the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the style and iconStyle I was able to achieve this.

```
       <FloatingActionButton style={{height: 21, width: 21}} iconStyle={{height: 21, width: 21}}>
         <SwapVert />
  </FloatingActionButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Button API](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#button).

You can set a property of `mini={true}` to get a smaller size floating action button.